# Load bundle according config parameter in AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony

I have two login implementations and I want to be able to load the one I want with a custom variable set in config.yml

```
# Type can be 'simple' or 'oauth2' for example
login:
  type: 'simple'
```

Is this possible? How can I do this? I have Symfony 2.7.

Comment: define parameters in parameters.yml and call `type: %myparam%` in the config.yml ?

Comment: the bundles are always initialized before the container is build.

Comment: Does that mean that it can't be done? @Federico

Comment: unless you create your own `Kernel.php`, no, you can't

Comment: Thank you very much! @Federico